# Can't get replacement icons to display

Tags: html, image, css

On [this page](http://54.68.45.200/user/dashboard) (Login: admin | admin123), I am trying to replace the current images with custom icons. I have opened the relevant CSS file and updated the file path for the new image but it doesn't display. I have also noticed something weird with the current images in use.

This is one of the icons I want changed:

[image: Icon to be replaced]

This is the new image I want to replace it with:

[image: New Image]

I can't seem to understand why the developers decided to use the complicated image below, but this, along with the CSS in use seems to be the cause of my problem. I understand a little CSS and I've been trying to wrap my head around this one for over 4 hours now but I'm not getting anywhere. I can't even get part of the image to show up.

[This](http://pastie.org/10050584) is the CSS responsible for displaying the icons. I would appreciate any clue as to what's happening here and how I can achieve my objectives.

Comment: do you have an image with two icons (side-by-side)? - the original images have two icons on the same 'file' and on hover, it slides 175px to the side to reveal one or the other (i.e. mouseon or mouseout) - do you have to simulate the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is find this line in the css file, and change the background url to your new image

```
#examinations_button {
  background: #fff url(../../images/dashboard_buttons/<newimagename>.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

#examinations_button:hover {
  background: #fff url(../../images/dashboard_buttons/<newimagename>.png) 0    0 no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I mentioned in the question above that I had opened the associated CSS file and updated the file path. This isn't an issue with the file path, I think the system is using a part of the image for display and hover and I'm seeking to use a single image for both. Maybe?

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your question. What it's doing on hover is a CSS trick that's been around for a while. The picture is technically 1 image, but it's actually 2 images (normal and hover state) that are side by side in the main image, then css is simply targeting different areas of that 1 image on hover or not. All you would need to do is edit both CSS selectors (normal and hover) to target your new picture. Answer updated

Comment: Thank you very much @mituw16. This is an interesting trick and one I will look into. Have a nice day!

Comment: Or remove the hover state (since it does not do anything) and reduce your page size...

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a 'hover' image, you could replace your icon image and for the hover effect, use a border around it instead.  Something like:

```
#admission_button {
    background:#fff url(../../images/dashboard_buttons/YOUR_NEW_ICON) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
#admission_button:hover { border: 1px solid gray; }
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion, Ochi. I will definitely use this.

Comment: You may need to leave a margin on the regular (non-hover) image of `1px` and then remove the margin on the `:hover` state (set it back to zero as it is replaced by the border) to avoid the 'wiggling' effect

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the url of the background on dashboard.css, moreover lokking your css path (`http://54.68.45.200/stylesheets/user/#dashboard.css?1427142532`), you may have a cache system for your assets, you have to flush it;

```
#examinations_button {
  background: #fff url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVsEt.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

#examinations_button:hover {
  background: #fff url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVsEt.png) 0    0 no-repeat;
}
```

modifying the background url on Chrome Dev Tools worked for me

Comment: but then on hover, it would change back to the original image (the one he is trying to remove)

Comment: Edited : I have forgotten the :hover